# How to simulate "making a necktie" with blender?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Here is the solution with Marvelous Designer: [[link]](http://www.marvelousdesigner.com/community/forum/Show-off-and-Learn/791)

Is it possible to do it with blender (e.g. cloth simulation)? So that by applying different magnitude of force, we get different outcome shape of the tie?

Thanks

DS